What happens when a Circle of Stars druid hits 0 HP while in Starry Form?
I can't find anywhere that fully touches on this.
Typically, when a druid uses Wild Shape (WS), they turn into another beast giving them the extra HP.
When the Circle of Stars druid enters WS, they maintain their humanoid form. Would they go back to where their HP was prior to entering WS after hitting 0 HP, or would they simply be knocked unconscious/die as normal?

You become Unconscious, or Dead, exactly as if you weren't in Starry Form
Starry Form comes with no hit points of its own, unlike normal Wild Shape. The rules for it specifically state you "retain your game statistics", and gives no special rules for hit points like regular Wild Shape does, nor does it refer to Wild Shape's rule in this regard. You "take on a starry form, rather than transforming into a beast" (emphasis added).
Since it has nothing in common with Wild Shape aside from requiring you to expend a use of Wild Shape to enter it, it has no special hit point rules, and upon reaching zero HP, you fall unconscious or die as normal.

Thank you! I was coming to that conclusion when re-reading it. Especially with the section stating, "It ends early if you dismiss it (no action required), are incapacitated, die, or use this feature again."
Again, thank you for that verification.

@JackSkell96: Incapacitated can occur for reasons aside from dropping to zero HP, since it's part of the Paralyzed, Petrified, Stunned, and Unconscious conditions (only the last of which ends normal Wild Shape). That clause doesn't support or weaken the argument.
